# How can i get my webscraper to skip over information I cant parse so it doesn't break.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, web-scraping

I've created this webscraper and when it runs it will break because I do not have a rule to keep running if it can't parse certian information. I am taking names and numbers of real estate agents however not everyone has their number on the website, when i run into a realtor without a number the script will stop working and return an error. I am a beginner at this and cant find the proper way to get it to keep looping between pages if the required information isnt found. it just stops when it can't find anymore information. I am aware this is a noob question but for the life of me I cannot get it to keep running over the missed information.

```
import requests
from requests import get
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange

from time import sleep
from random import randint

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}

my_url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az/pg-2'

#opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
#read page 
page_html = uClient.read()
#close page
uClient.close()

pages = np.arange(1, 30, 1)

for page in pages:

    page = requests.get("https://www.realtor.com/realestateagents/phoenix_az/pg-2" + str(page) + "&ref_=adv_nxt", headers=headers)


#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

sleep(randint(2,10))

#finds all realtors on page 
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"agent-list-card clearfix"})

for container in containers:
    name = container.find('div', class_='agent-name text-bold')
    agent_name = name.text.strip()

    number = container.find('div', class_='agent-phone hidden-xs hidden-xxs')
    agent_number = number.text.strip()


print("name: " + agent_name)
print("number: " + agent_number)
```

below is the rule i wrote to try and solve this issue however i am not great at this and not entirely sure where i am going wrong yet.

```
nv = container.find_all('div', attrs={'number': 'nv'})
number = nv[1].text if len(nv) > 1 else '-'
```

Comment: Probably you can use the try - except block. It will enable you to continue on errors. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about the `try` and `except` block for catching errors instead of breaking in between.

```
for container in containers:
    try:
        name = container.find('div', class_='agent-name text-bold')
        agent_name = name.text.strip()
    except:
        pass
    try:
        number = container.find('div', class_='agent-phone hidden-xs hidden-xxs')
        agent_number = number.text.strip()
    except:
        pass
```

This was the basic example on how you can use this. But writing only `except` will catch all the errors you might encounter. You need to see what errors you are seeing in order to catch them. This way of using except is not recommended just FYI, however you can still use it.
A better approach would be to use except with the exception you want to handle. For example, if you want to handle the Attribute Error, use the same code as:

```
for container in containers:
    try:
        name = container.find('div', class_='agent-name text-bold')
        agent_name = name.text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    try:
        number = container.find('div', class_='agent-phone hidden-xs hidden-xxs')
        agent_number = number.text.strip()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

You can also choose to use `if-else`. If the condition is true, then it'd print the name and number, otherwise you can set another condition in `else` block.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Hamza! The end goal is to get all of this information exported into a csv file. I am only collecting names and numbers for the time being. If I am running through 35 pages of information which rule do you think would be best to use? thanks again!

Comment: I'd suggest the `try-except`. I use it like everyone else all the time, no matter the number of pages. And it really depends what you want to do every time.

Comment: Okay I believe I got the try except set up, however now i am getting an expected an indented block error.

Comment: try:
 name = container.find('div', class_='agent-name text-bold')
 agent_name = name.a.text.strip()
except AttributeError:
 print("-")